# change i3wm workspace / windows status to urgent

Tags: ssh, i3-window-manager

I have a shell script that I run on a distant server, and I'd like the i3 window status to become urgent so that the workspace button becomes red. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many terminals can set the urgent flag on their windows if the *bell character* - `\a` - is printed. So

```sh
me-runs-long-time.sh ; echo -e '\a'
```

Should do the trick. Remember that *i3* will immediately remove the urgent flag when the window is focused or when it is already focused. So you can test if this works by running

```sh
sleep 3; echo -e '\a'
```

and immediately focusing another window.

**Note**: The terminal might need to be configured for this behavior:

- For `rxvt-unicode` the resource `urgentOnBell` needs to be set to `True`. For `xterm` it is the resource `bellIsUrgent`. You can set resources in `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults`, depending on your distribution.

  ```sh
  XTerm*bellIsUrgent: True
  URxvt.urgentOnBell: True
  ```

  Either run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` or restart your X session to enable the changes (for new terminals).
- For `termite` this can be enabled by setting the `urgent_on_bell` option to `true` in its configuration - `~/.config/termite/config`:

  ```sh
  [options]
  urgent_on_bell = true
  ```

  This will immediately work on any new termite window.

---

Of course, the above solution depends on you remembering to append `; echo -e '\a'` every time. There are a few ways to automate this. For example:

- An easy way out would be to just output `\a` at the appropriate time in the script itself. This of course requires write access and would need to be done for every script separately.
- If you use `zsh`, you could add the following to your `~/.zshrc` (on the remote machine):

  ```sh
  # this may already be in your ~/.zshrc
  autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
  # duration in seconds after which a bell should be sent
  typeset -i LONGRUNTIME=60
  # function to save time at which a command was started
  save_starttime () {
    starttime=$SECONDS
  }
  # function to print \a if the command took longer than LONGRUNTIME
  set_longrunning_alert () {
    if ((LONGRUNTIME > 0 && SECONDS - starttime >= LONGRUNTIME)); then
      print "\a"
    fi
  }
  # run save_starttime before a command is executed
  add-zsh-hook preexec save_starttime
  # run set_longrunning_alert after a command finishes (before the prompt)
  add-zsh-hook precmd set_longrunning_alert
  ```

  This will automatically print a *bell character* if a command took longer than one minute.
- If you use `bash` you could use the following on the remote machine.

  ```sh
  PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -e "\a"'
  ```

  This will run `echo -e "\a"` *every* time before the primary prompt is issued. While this will mark the window urgent after every command, it should not really be noticable in most cases because will not keep the urgent flag on focused windows.

If you use the settings for `bash` or `zsh` also on your local machine, you will also be notified in case of the SSH connection dying (in the case of `zsh` only if it dies after `LONGRUNTIME` seconds). Assuming of course that you start `ssh` from your shell.

Comment: Wow! Stellar answer. I'm trying to get it to work. I use gnome-terminal (a legacy from my earlier uses of linux)

Comment: I could not get it to work with `urxvt` or `gnome-terminal`, but it works with xterm, so I just need to know how to make it `gnome-terminal` recognize the bell as urgent I guess. Also : the `wmctrl` trick [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/47h3cm/how_can_i_trigger_a_urgent_workspace_notification/) works

Comment: got it to work with urxvt too :)

Comment: I asked [a separate question](http://superuser.com/questions/1056791/have-bell-mean-window-is-urgent-with-gnome-terminal) for the gnome-terminal problem