# Have bell mean window is urgent with gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3-window-manager

How can I configure the terminal bell to mark the current window as urgent in gnome-terminal ? Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1053640/change-i3wm-workspace-windows-status-to-urgent). I'm using i3wm . Currently `echo -e "\a"` does nothing even if I'm on another workspace.

In short, I'm looking for the gnome-terminal equivalent for

```
XTerm*bellIsUrgent: True
URxvt.urgentOnBell: True
```

Comment: It seems like this may be what you're looking for.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/228096/terminal-bell-doesnt-ring

Comment: I tried that, but this is to get some sound, which does work. What I want is also to have the bell recognized as urgent, and have the workspace / window preview go red (which works with urxvt or xterm, btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the answer you would like to get, but at the moment this is not possible, at least with the official version of `gnome-terminal`.

There is a [feature request on the gnome bug tracker (#557593)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557593) from 2008, which calls for this feature. There even were some patches that implemented this feature but they were never merged into the main branch.

Strangely, the underlying *VTE* widget, which is utilized by `gnome-terminal` - and which is also part of the Gnome project, has had the ability to set the urgent flag since before the above bug was created. (See  [this bugreport (#329108)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=329108)).

There is also a [bug report on Launchpad (#272749)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/272749) which has some more information.

The comments in the bug reports seem to indicate that it is still possible to apply the patches onto newer versions of `gnome-terminal`. So, if you want to keep using it, you probably have to compile it on your own with the necessary patches.

Comment: Thanks for the stellar answer, I guess I'll look for a new terminal emulator this week-end. I'm not even using GNOME, so it would be logical to question this choice.